# regsub -all for multiple match is not working

Tags: tcl

Using the below regular expression trying to capure pf2(y,[],[],n) and insert [],[] after second square bracket [] as like pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n)

```
    set test {hk,pf2(y,[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no)),hk,pf2(y,[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no))}
```

the below regsub is working for the last match, but it is not matching all the match

```
    regsub -all -- {,(pf2\([y|n]),\[(.*)\],\[(.*)\],(.)} $test {,\1,[\2],[],[],[\3],\4} test
```

Actual output:

```
    hk,pf2(y,[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no)),hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no))
```

Expected Output:

```
    hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no)),hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no))
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regular expression is greedy and matches as much as it can. We can see this if we do this slight variation (inserting highly visible markers is a good way to diagnose RE problems when the wrong thing is being matched):

```
% regsub -all {,(pf2\([y|n]),\[(.*)\],\[(.*)\],(.)} $test {>>>>,\1,[\2],[],[],[\3],\4<<<<}
hk>>>>,pf2(y,[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no)),hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],f<<<<lags(no,no,no))
```

Changing the greediness of the quantifiers (`.*` to `.*?`) makes it do what you expect:

```
% regsub -all -- {,(pf2\([y|n]),\[(.*?)\],\[(.*?)\],(.)} $test {,\1,[\2],[],[],[\3],\4}
hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no)),hk,pf2(y,[],[],[],[],n),[y:0],flags(no,no,no))
```

Comment: @Tamilan By the way, you probably want to use `[yn]` instead of `[y|n]`, unless you want `|` included in the set of characters matched…